# How can I go from the most general case of jump-diffusion process to the particular one?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In different books (e.g. Applied Stochastic Control of Jump Diffusions) I note that the jump-diffusion process (in one dimension) can be described as a solution of
\begin{equation}\label{diffusionWithJumps}
dS_t = \mu(S_{t}, t) dt + \beta(S_{t}, t)dW_t + \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(S_{t-}, t, z) \tilde{N}(dt, dz),
\end{equation}

The special case of jump-diffusion process is a Merton's model of the form
\begin{equation}
S_t = s e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t + \sum_{i=1}^{N_t}Y_i},
\end{equation}
which is a solution to
\begin{equation}\label{expLevyModel}
dS_t = r S_{t} dt + \sigma S_{t} dW_t + S_{t-}(Y_t-1)dN_t.
\end{equation}

My question is: How should I set $\mu(S_{t-}, t)$, $\beta(S_{t-}, t)$ and other components in the first of given formula to obtain the last formula. In other words how can I go from the most general case to this particular one (Merton's model).

Comment: Choose $\mu(S_t, t)=rS_t$ and $\beta(S_t, t)=\sigma S_t$. Is this really your question?

Comment: Ok, it is clear. What about the integral part of this SDE? How can from this obtain $S_{t-}(Y_t-1)dN_t$

Comment: That I am not so sure only because I actually am also in the middle of reconciling the details of jump measures myself (I recently went through the derivation of the Merton PIDE with some handwaving), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I come a bit late to the party and I am going to admit that my answer is probably not going to be the most formal but here is the attempt.

In the Merton model, we are looking at a compound Poisson process where $lnY  \sim  N(\mu_y, \sigma_y)$ and $N_t \sim Poisson(\lambda)$

If you take your equation for

$$
S_t = S_0e^{\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t + \sigma dW_t+\sum^{N_t}_{t=1}Y_t}
$$

and let's replace $W_t$ by $X$ and apply Ito for jump processes we get the following:

$$ df_t = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial'' f}{\partial X^2} \right)dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}dW_t + \left[f(S_t+Y_t) - f(S_t)\right]dN_t$$

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = (r-\sigma^2/2)S_t$$
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial X} = \sigma S_t $$
$$\frac{\partial'' S}{\partial X^2} = \sigma^2 S_t $$
$$\left[f(S_t+Y_t) - f(S_t)\right] =S_te^{Y_t} - S_t =  S_t\left(Y_t-1\right)$$

And so replacing the terms above we get:
$$dS_t = S_t(r-\sigma^2/2 + \sigma^2/2)dt + S_t\sigma dW_t + S_t(Y_t-1)dN_t $$
Which simplifies to
$$dS_t = S_trdt + S_t\sigma dW_t + S_t(Y_t-1)dN_t $$

and so you have that $\mu(S_{t-},t) = rS_t$, $\beta(S_{t-},t) = \sigma S_t$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} (S_{t-},t,z)\tilde N(dt,dz) =S_t(Y_t-1)dN_t$ which I believe it can also be written as $\prod^{dN_t}_{j=1} \left(Y_j -1 \right)$ because $S_t$ already incorporates all the jumps up to time $t$